# Nested VLOOKUP formula

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

I am programming a google sheet that tracks hours put in by associates (recorded from a google form).

After the results are populated into a response google sheet (Sheet 3, for reference) (note: "Week" column is a formula: `=WEEKNUM(B2)`):

[image]

I would like to, then, on another sheet (Sheet 4), add up the hours by week:

[image]

(disclaimer: pure coincidence the female did less work)

However, I am having trouble getting the proper formula. These are what I tried:

1. `=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet3!A:A,Sheet3!D:D, 1)`. But this had an error: `Function VLOOKUP parameter 3 value is 0. It should be greater than or equal to 1.` (which makes no sense because the parameter is actually `1`.
2. `=VLOOKUP(B$1, Sheet3!C:D, 2)`, but this only returned `7:15` (this makes sense, it is finding the last value for `Bob`).

I'm stumped. Am I barking up the wrong tree with `VLOOKUP`?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer (with the help of this page: https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!category-topic/docs/how-do-i/i_IQkC15vDg):

`VLOOKUP` was the wrong formula. Instead, I needed a combination of `SUM` and `FILTER`:

```
=SUM(FILTER(Sheet3!$D:$D,Sheet3!$B:$B=$A2,Sheet3!$C:$C=B$1))
```

This produced the desired output.